# Stata output variable to matrix with ebalance

Tags: variables, matrix, stata

I'm using the `ebalance` Stata package to calculate post-stratification weights, and I'd like to convert the weights output (`_webal`, which is generated as a `double` with format `%10.0g`) to a matrix.

I'd like to normalize all weights in the "control" group, but I can't seem to convert the variable to a matrix in order to manipulate the weights individually (I'm a novice to Stata, so I was just going to do this using a loop––I'd normally just export and do this in `R`, but I have to calculate results within a bootstrap). I *can*, however, *view* the individual-level weights produced by the output, and I can use them to calculate sample statistics.

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question.

Your problem is that you have a variable that you want to do some calculations on, and since you can't just use R and you don't know how to do those (unspecified) calculations directly in Stata, you have decided that the first step is to create a matrix from the variable.